# Minify all CSS and Javascript in a directory

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python script that will package the contents of a directory and minify all of the JavaScript and CSS scripts.

If I used the code below (bottom of the post), and the directory structure inside of `theme_files` was such:

```
\
 |-assets\
 |        |-css\
 |        |     |-theme.css
 |        |     |-stylesheet.css
 |        |
 |        |-js\
 |        |    |-theme.js
 |        |    |-page.js
 |
 |-index.html
```

*(Is there a better way to do that?)*

It would output the whole directory structure into the generated `.pak` file properly. However, the minified css and javascript files have no content inside of them other than their own file name.

**Example:** the content of the file (supposedly minified) `theme.css` would be "theme.css"

That's it. Nothing else. One line.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

```
import io
import os
import zipfile
import rcssmin
import rjsmin

pakName = input("Theme Name: ").replace(" ", "_").lower()

themePak = zipfile.ZipFile(pakName +".tpk", "w")

for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("theme_files"):
    themePak.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith((".css", ".js")):
            themePak.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

        if filename.endswith(".css"):
            cssMinified = io.StringIO()
            cssMinified.write(rcssmin.cssmin(filename, keep_bang_comments=True))
            themePak.writestr(os.path.join(dirname, filename), cssMinified.getvalue())

        if filename.endswith(".js"):
            jsMinified = io.StringIO()
            jsMinified.write(rjsmin.jsmin(filename, keep_bang_comments=True))
            themePak.writestr(os.path.join(dirname, filename), jsMinified.getvalue())

themePak.close()
```

Comment: I would suggest to use gulp  http://gulpjs.com/ for something like this since it has everything you need built in.

Comment: @Koborl No thanks, it needs to be python.

Comment: `rcssmin.cssmin()` and `rjsmin.jsmin()` expect the first element to be the CSS respectively JS code to minify as string. You have to open and read the CSS and JS files by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Squall,

> rcssmin.cssmin() and rjsmin.jsmin() expect the first element to be the CSS respectively JS code to minify as string. You have to open and read the CSS and JS files by yourself.

---

```
if filename.endswith(".css"):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r") as assetfile:
        assetdata = assetfile.read().replace("\n", "")
    cssMinified = io.StringIO()
    cssMinified.write(rcssmin.cssmin(assetdata, keep_bang_comments=True))
    themePak.writestr(os.path.join(dirname, filename), cssMinified.getvalue())

if filename.endswith(".js"):
    with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r") as assetfile:
        assetdata = assetfile.read().replace("\n", "")
    jsMinified = io.StringIO()
    jsMinified.write(rjsmin.jsmin(assetdata, keep_bang_comments=True))
    themePak.writestr(os.path.join(dirname, filename), jsMinified.getvalue())
```

The changes in my `if` statements in the above code open the asset files as strings, then pass them along for minification.

I learned the hard way that you have to be sure to `os.path.join()` the filenames and the directories.

```
with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r") as assetfile:
    assetdata = assetfile.read().replace("\n", "")
```

Then minify `assetdata` and write to file. (In this case, memory object.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need minify (or/and merge) JS/CSS file : I created [Minifpy](https://github.com/SamuelDauzon/Minifpy) : a tool to merge and minify JS and CSS file by using Python.

Minifpy uses a very easy JSON configuration file to define if files must be merge , minify or not :

```
{
    "js": {
        "minify_files": [
            {"from": "static/file.js", "to":"static/file.min.js"},
        ],
        "merge_files": [
            {"from" : ["static/file1.js", "static/file2.js"], "to":"static/public.js", "to_min": "static/public.min.js"}
        ]
    },
    "css" : {
        "minify_files": [
            {"from": "static/file.css", "to":"static/file.min.css"},
        ],
        "merge_files": [
            {"from" : ["static/file1.css", "static/file2.css"], "to":"static/public.css", "to_min": "static/public.min.css"}
        ]
    }
}
```

But Minifpy can't automatically minify each file on a project.

Minifpy detect any modifications on JS/CSS files and merge/minify them automatically (useful for development).